# C++ LNK1120 Fatal Error: 1 unresolved externals

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to compile this code using MS Visual Studio Professional 2010 and it's giving me a build error LNK1120 Fatal Error: 1 unresolved externals.
Here's the code...

```
// Program Typos prints three integer numbers, sums the numbers, calculates
// the average, and prints the sum and the average of the three numbers.

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int ONE = 5;
const int TWO = 6;
const int THREE = 7;

int main ()
{
    int sum;
    float average;


    cout  << fixed  << showpoint;

    cout << setw(5) << ONE  << TWO  << THREE << endl;
    sum = ONE + TWO + THREE;
    average = sum / 3;
    cout  << " The sum is "  << sum  << " and the average is " \
      << average  <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the unresolved external? This compiles fine.

Comment: Your error lies elsewhere. You didn't prepare this question thoroughly.

Comment: In your question, you calculate the average as an integer. In this particular case, that happens to work out all right, but that's a mere coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility is missing `WinMain` (or its variant). To resolve goto Project Settings, Linker -> System, and select `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`.

It that's not the problem, kindly paste entire error message.